# Beautiful Soap find / try different class elements with possible 'NoneType' errors

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, try-catch

I'm using beautiful soup to get elements off a url. There are elements on the page that the class name changes depending on the value and percentage (up, down, flat). Obviously, if I try `soup.find('div', class_='down-indicator')` and it is a positive indicator I will get an error like this: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`. I need a pythonic way to loop through or try the 3 possible class options without the error breaking my code.

I've also tried `res = soup.find('div', class_='down-indicator')` to then do a `if res is None...` but it does not return `None` it returns an error.

Any info and learning would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance and this is my terrible attempt at some code:

These 2 urls have different class names for same area depending on on element.

```
url = 'http://www.stockx.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-380-lmnte-infants'
url = 'http://www.stockx.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-350-oxford-tan'
```

And these are the exact `find()` functions for the elements because it can be up, down, or flat:

```
soup.find('div', class_='last-sale-value market-dir market-dir-down').find('div', class_='dollar').text
soup.find('div', class_='last-sale-value market-dir market-dir-up').find('div', class_='dollar').text
soup.find('div', class_='last-sale-value market-dir market-dir-static').find('div', class_='dollar').text


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

try:
    result = soup.find('div', class_='up-indicator').text
    result = soup.find('div', class_='down-indicator').text
    result = soup.find('div', class_='flat-indicator').text
except:
    pass
```

Comment: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'` means your `soup` has a `None` (blank) value

Comment: @Shijith the soup is there. Whats not there is the element I'm searching for in the soup. I can `print(soup)` and see content no problem.

Comment: What's the url of your page?

Comment: Adding actual url up above @jizhihaoSAMA

Comment: For each of two url samples, what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting for http://www.stockx.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-380-lmnte-infants I want the $0 value under the div class `last-sale-value market-dir market-dir-static` and for http://www.stockx.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-350-oxford-tan I want the -$341 in the div class `last-sale-value market-dir market-dir-down`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, the solution is fairly simple:

```
soup.select_one('div.dollar').text
```

The output is the target dollar amount of the relevant page.

Comment: this is perfect! I didnt see this `select_one()` function. Does it just essentially find any type of element given the name? Like if this was not a div could I use `span.name`? Ill check mark this one, thank you!

Comment: @Andre `select_one()` is one of BS's many css selectors. Definitively worth reading up on it!